# problem of saving a large panda data frame to pickle or json?

Tags: json, pandas, pickle

I tried to save a large panda dataframe to JSON file

[[image: data[1]]

I used these ways

```
df.to_pickle("dfSentsOB.pkl")
```

Unfortunately, I faced with this error, can anyone know what is the reason?

but it says:

```
no default __reduce__ due to non-trivial __cinit__
```

and also this way:

```
df.to_json(orient='table')
```

It gives this error

```
Maximum recursion level reached
```

I only want to save my data in order to load it again, In my view the problem is kind of related to the size of data and also my setting for panda since before setting my data has been saved.

I used this setting in my panda data frame to see  all words:

```
options = {"compact": True, "bg": "#09a3d5",
           "color": "white", "font": "Source Sans Pro","collapse_phrases":False}
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 260)
```

If you know any other way (except csv) please let me know?

Comment: Are you just reading this data into a DataFrame and saving it to pickle ? Please mention small code snippet if anything is going on in between.reading and pickling this data.

Comment: hi, yes, I read a data frame I add some columns (for instance with spacy, I add tags, entity ) and I want to save it as pickle or JSON or any other format, but I tried pickle, JSON and hdf all faced with an error. northing speciall, I add some columns only ...

Comment: Could you please try converting DF to Dict and pickle/ Json it ?

Comment: tnx for message, I tried this way  ```import mpu
df=df.to_dict()
mpu.io.write('dfObs.pickle', df)```again the same error!  ```no default __reduce__ due to non-trivial __cinit__```

Comment: @Hima, I really stuck in this, any idea would be very appreciated

Comment: Hi Would it be possible to upload your sample data ? I don't see any particular issue pickling this data.

Comment: I have upload my sample data as pickle! then I read it by                    ```df = pd.read_pickle(path)```   It is a text data, each row is a sentence, then I used spaCy to add entity to each row as new column and also labels ..then as it is written IN MY LAST MESSGAEsome set up to see each sents in panda...but every time that I tried to pickle or JSON it faced with error!

Comment: @ Hima any thought?

Comment: @hima It could be connected to spaCY, SInce Spacy is written in cython language. my error says that ```no default __reduce__ due to non-trivial __cinit__```  I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: Do you have any type conversion in your code? Like  ```numpy.float64```, ```numpy.int32``` then change it to ```int```, ```float```. it also could by opposite deppen on your python version if version >= 3 then use ```int``` else use  ```numpy.int32```. Another fix is little bit darty which is increase you ```recursion```, like ```sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)```

Comment: How about putting your ideas to the test? You said it might be related to the size of data. Did you check that? What if you save half the rows? The other half? A quarter? A random sample? Two rows? One row? Or it might be related to spacy. What in your DataFrame can be related to spacy? What if you save only the original columns? Only the new columns?

Comment: I put a answer if you have look

Answer (score 1):

This code can read you csv and give you JSON object. For more [details](http://geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-to_dict). You can use python `csv` and `json` library then you do not need to use any other library like `pandas` or `mpu`.

```
import pandas as pd
csvFile = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("path/csvFile.csv", sep = ",", header = 0, index_col = False))
csvFile.to_json("path/jsonFile.json", orient = "records", date_format = "epoch", double_precision = 10, force_ascii = True, date_unit = "ms", default_handler = None)
```

Comment: please read the main question, the problem is different!  I have a panda data frame file and I add some column with Spacy, now when I want to convert it to JSON or pickle I faced with error as in main question above! I my guess that since Spacy used cython pickling or making JSON faced with problem.